# State property has empty object instead of actual value set by action

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm fetching data via API and want to show error message if the request fails. I'm dispatching setDuplicatesError that should set state.error property to error message. This is how my reducer looks like:

```
export function setDuplicatesPending(loading) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DUPLICATES_PENDING',
        loading
    }
}

export function setDuplicates(duplicates) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DUPLICATES_SUCCESS',
        duplicates
    };
}

export function setDuplicatesError(error) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DUPLICATES_FAILURE',
        error
    };
}

export default function duplicatesData(state = {loading: true}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DUPLICATES_FAILURE':
            console.log("Failure action is dispatched.", action.error);
            return {...state, error: action.error};

        case 'FETCH_DUPLICATES_PENDING':
            console.log("Loading action is dispatched.")
            return {...state, loading: action.loading };

        case 'FETCH_DUPLICATES_SUCCESS':
            return {...state, rows: action.duplicates, loading: false };    

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

action.error has the actual error message which I can see in console:

```
Failure action is dispatched. TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL...
```

but when I try displaying it in my component

```
render() {
        return (<div> {JSON.stringify(this.props.state)}</div>)
    }
```

I'm getting the following:

```
{"duplicatesData":{"error":{}}}
```

Loading action works fine and shows true/false in state when I display it.

What's causing this behavior?

This is how I create store:

```
  import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from "redux";
  import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
  import duplicatesData from "./myReducer";

  const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  export default () => {
      const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
          duplicatesData
        }),
        composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
      );
      store.asyncReducers = {};  
      return store;
    };
```

and link it it to the component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
      state
    };
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
          fetchDuplicates: () => dispatch(fetchDuplicates())
      }
  }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DuplicatesTable);
```

Comment: look in the redux tools if the error still in the global state, another stuff check the connect have you been included mapStateToProps

Comment: @Nemer redux tools show {} for error. Yes, I included mapStateToProps to the component. As I said this.props.state.loading works ok.

Comment: did you add your reducers to the store ?

Comment: can you show mapStateToProps and the name of the reducer file?

Comment: @Nemer sure, I updated the post

Comment: const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 state
}); //can you try this way.

Comment: and yeah other stuff be sure the dispatch not called after FETCH_DUPLICATES_FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

if loading actions works fine you can forget to connect your reducers to the store

an example of the store configuring

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers  } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import duplicatesData from './duplicatesData';


  const reducers = combineReducers({
    duplicatesData
  });
const initialState = {};

createStore(
        reducers,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
    );
```

Comment: If i forgot to connect my reducer, I wouldn't get true or false value for this.props.state.loading

Comment: did you try to pass a simple text via an action (setDuplicatesError), not an error ?

Comment: Try to pass error.message instead of error object or use JSON.stringify(error)